# JavaFX Editing TreeView with custom object

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I need to make TreeView editable, and the TreeView has TreeItem with a generic type `Content`.
I managed to display my objects on TreeView by overriding `toString()` in the `Content` class. However, even though I know the custom editing feature has something to do with CellFactory, I couldn't get it to work.

The editing I wanted to implement works like below:

1. When I start editing a cell by double-clicking or press Enter, a TextField shows.
2. If it has ':' seperator in the cell when a user has done editing, save the former and latter respectively in `name` and `description` in the class `Property` which extends `Content`.
3. If not, save a content in `name` in the class `Concept` which extends `Content`.

MainController.java

```
package jsh.hiercards;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTreeView;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTreeCell;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    public JFXTreeView<Content> treeView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        TreeItem<Content> root = new TreeItem<>(new Concept("TESTROOT", null));
        root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(new Concept("TESTCONCEPT", (Concept) root.getValue())));
        root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(new Property("TESTPROPERTY", (Concept) root.getValue(), "DESCRIPTION")));
        treeView.setRoot(root);
    }

    @FXML
    public void startEdit(TreeView.EditEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Start");
    }

    @FXML
    public void commitEdit(TreeView.EditEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Commit");
    }

    @FXML
    public void cancelEdit(TreeView.EditEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Cancel");
    }

    @FXML
    public void typeHandle(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Type");
    }
}
```

Content.java

```
package jsh.hiercards;

import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;

public abstract class Content {

    public String name;
    public Concept parent;

    private Content() {
    }

    public Content(String name, Concept parent) {
        this.name = name;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public abstract String toString();
}
```

Concept.java

```
package jsh.hiercards;

import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;

public class Concept extends Content {

    public Concept(String name, Concept parent) {
        super(name, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Property.java

```
package jsh.hiercards;

import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;

public class Property extends Content {

    public String description;

    public Property(String name, Concept parent, String description) {
        super(name, parent);
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " : " + description;
    }
}
```

How can I code them to make a editing feature which works?

-- Sorry for poor English, I'm a foreign student :(

Comment: *" I managed to display my objects on `TreeView` by overriding `toString()` in the `Content` class.*" This is not the recommended approach. You should customize the `TreeCell` to display the tree item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work for your controller. If you use a `TextFieldTreeCell` there is no need to handle the edit events yourself.

It's also not good practice to use `toString()` to determine how an object is displayed in the UI (it "pollutes" the data model with code that is essentially implementing part of the view; you may, and probably will, want the `toString()` method to provide different information, e.g. for debugging).

So something like:

```
package jsh.hiercards;

public abstract class Content {

    private String name;
    private Concept parent;

    private Content() {
    }

    public Content(String name, Concept parent) {
        this.name = name;
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name ;
    }

    public Concept getParent() {
        return parent ;
    }

}
```

```
package jsh.hiercards;

public class Concept extends Content {

    public Concept(String name, Concept parent) {
        super(name, parent);
    }

}
```

```
package jsh.hiercards;
    
public class Property extends Content {

    private String description;

    public Property(String name, Concept parent, String description) {
        super(name, parent);
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description ;
    }
}
```

```
package jsh.hiercards;

import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton;
import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTreeView;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTreeCell;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.util.StringConverter ;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MainController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    public JFXTreeView<Content> treeView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        treeView.setCellFactory(tv -> new TextFieldTreeCell<>(new StringConverter<>() {
            @Override
            public Content fromString(String text) {
                TreeItem<Content> parentItem = getTreeItem().getParent();
                Content parent = parentItem == null ? null : parentItem.getValue() ;
                String[] tokens = text.split(":", 2);
                if (tokens.length < 2) {
                    return new Concept(tokens[0], parent);
                } else return new Property(tokens[0], parent, tokens[1]);
            }

            @Override
            public String toString(Content content) {
                if (content instanceof Property property) {
                    return property.getName() + " : " + property.getDescription();
                }
                return content.getName();
            }
        }));

        TreeItem<Content> root = new TreeItem<>(new Concept("TESTROOT", null));

        root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(new Concept("TESTCONCEPT", (Concept) root.getValue())));
        root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(new Property("TESTPROPERTY", (Concept) root.getValue(), "DESCRIPTION")));
        treeView.setRoot(root);
    }

    /*
    @FXML
    public void startEdit(TreeView.EditEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Start");
    }

    @FXML
    public void commitEdit(TreeView.EditEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Commit");
    }

    @FXML
    public void cancelEdit(TreeView.EditEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Cancel");
    }
    */

    @FXML
    public void typeHandle(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Type");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for such a kind answer, but I get an error "Cannot resolve method 'getTreeItem()'".
Can I instead use ``tv.getTreeItem(tv.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex())``?

Comment: @QueN That's a bit hacky, but it works.  The problem here is that your hierarchy is represented twice; once in the model (`Content` has a `parent` property), and once in the `TreeItem` structure.